# Generate PDF of Protected Django Webpage with Attachments

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pdf, reportlab

So I'm trying to generate a PDF of a view that I have in a django web application.  This view is protected, meaning the user has to be logged in and have specific permission to view the page.  I also have some attachments (stored in the database as `FileFields`) that I would like to append to the end of the PDF.

I've read most of the posts I could find on how to generate PDFs from a webpage using `pdfkit` or `reportlab`, but all of them fail for me for some reason or another.

Currently, the closest I've gotten is successfully generating a PDF of the page using `pdfkit`, but this requires me to remove the restrictions that require the user to be logged in and have page permissions, which really isn't an option long term.  I found a couple posts that discuss printing pdfs on protected pages and providing login information, but I couldn't get any of that to work.

I haven't found anything on how to include attachments, and don't really know where to start with that.

I'm more than happy to update this question with more information or snippets of code if need be, but there's quite a few moving parts here and I don't want to flood people with useless information.  Let me know if there's any other information I should provide, and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working!  Through a combination of PyPDF2 and pdfkit, I got this to work pretty simply.  It works on protected pages because django takes care of getting the complete html as a string, which I just pass to pdfkit.  It also supports appending attachments, but I doubt (though I haven't tested) that it works with anything other than pdfs.

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import pdfkit

def append_pdf(pdf, output):
    [output.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num)) for page_num in range(pdf.numPages)]


def render_to_pdf():
    t = get_template('app/template.html')
    c = {'context_data': context_data}

    html = t.render(c)
    pdfkit.from_string(html, 'path/to/file.pdf')

    output = PdfFileWriter()
    append_pdf(PdfFileReader(open('path/to/file.pdf', "rb")), output)

    attaches = Attachment.objects.all()

    for attach in attaches:
        append_pdf(PdfFileReader(open(attach.file.path, "rb")), output)

    output.write(open('path/to/file_with_attachments.pdf', "wb"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I was able to convert protected webpage to pdf in Django. the page however has 2 images which did not show up in the pdf. I also had an error stating failed to load file : ///relative/image/path. How can i ensure images are also included in the pdf using django

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to secure it, you could write a custom Authentication Backend that lets your server spoof users. Way over-kill but it would solve your problem and at least you get to learn about custom auth backends! (Note: You should be using HTTPS.)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

1. Create auth backend in `app/auth_backends.py`
2. Add `app.auth_backends.SpoofAuthBackend` backend to `settings.py` that takes a `shared_secret` and `user_id`.
3. Create a URL route like `url(r'^spoof-user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', 'app.views.spoof_user', name="spoof-user")`
4. Add the view `spoof_user` that must invoke both `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` (which invokes backend in #1 above) and after getting user from `authenticate(...)` you pad the request with the user `django.contrib.auth.login(request, user)`. Finally, this view should return `HttpResponseForbidden` if the shared secret is wrong or `HttpResponseRedirect` to the PDF URL you actually want (after logging in to spoof user programmatically via `authenticate` and `login`).

You would probably want to create a random secret key each request using something like `cache.set('spoof-user-%s' % user_id, RANDOM_STRING, 30)` which persists shared secret for 30 seconds to allow time for request. Then perform `pdf_response = requests.get("%s?shared_secret=1a2b3c&redirect_uri=/path/to/pdf/" % reverse('spoof-user', kwargs={'user_id': 1234}))`. Your new view will test the provided `shared_secret` in auth backend, login user to request and perform redirect to `request.GET.get('redirect_uri')`.

Comment: I will also add that I generate all my PDFs entirely server-side using `wkhtmltopdf` but being able to spoof users can be useful for some projects. For example, just for admins or helpdesk staff to be able to login and view their projects to help troubleshoot support issues, etc.

Comment: I also just uploaded a gist showing usage of `django-wkhtmltopdf`: https://gist.github.com/pztrick/94a90908954bcdb5f672f00aa4d9b2de  Note that you need to refactor your views so they pass the same `context` dictionary to the template rather than accessing things like `request.user`.

Comment: that gist looks much more reasonable, and similar to something I was looking into...  I'll test with that.  Any thoughts on how I could append attachments to that?

Comment: Hi @Nealon! Here is a gist from another project of mine that has a couple functions to 1) merge PDFs to single PDF and 2) add PDFs into Zipfile attachment. My comment indicates that #1 was broken, but as this code was written a long time ago it may be fixed now. https://gist.github.com/pztrick/2e6bb623651079cb216c1e1b8b899253

Answer (score -1):

You can use [pdfkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit/0.4.1) to do that. You can retrieve the page using the url and pdfkit will handle the rest:

```
pdfkit.from_url('http://website.com/somepage', 'somepage.pdf')
```

You will have to properly access the page using the appropriate headers for it is protected of course:

```
options = {
    'cookie': [
        ('cookie-name1', 'cookie-value1'),
        ('cookie-name2', 'cookie-value2'),
    ]
}

pdfkit.from_url('http://website.com/somepage', 'somepage.pdf')
`
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  What would the structure of the options object look like to get the application to be able to login correctly?  I tried something like that before, as I noted in my question, but couldn't get it work.  I'm using the built in django user verification.  Also, wouldn't you have to pass that options object to pdfkit somehow?  And I still need to be able to add attachments.