# Auto-Expanding TextAreas on PDF Generated from Django Template

Tags: django, textarea, pdfkit

I'm using pdfkit to generate a PDF of a Django template (doing this by getting an HTML string of the page from Django's `get_template` and `render` functions and passing that string to pdfkit... see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884654/generate-pdf-of-protected-django-webpage-with-attachments)).

On this page, I have some TextArea's that can contain many lines of text, and by default, they just get cut off when generating the PDF.

I've tried to fix this by using some javascript libraries (I've tried several) to automatically expand the TextAreas on page load.  I can get these to work perfectly on normal pages, but when I try to include it on the PDF template, I get various errors ranging from not working at all to expanding the TextArea way too much.  My first assumption was that there was some styling differences that were causing the issues, but I'm fairly certain I've ruled that out.  I tried to load the PDF template directly as a view, and the TextArea's resized correctly, leading me to believe that there's something with pdfkits generation that isn't playing nicely with the resizing.

Given this, I tried to look if pdfkit has any suggestions for issues like this and couldn't find any, and I also tried to use different input types other than TextAreas, none of which were able to display newlines correctly.

I can't think of any other potential solutions at this point, and I'm open to suggestions.  Please let me know if you feel I should provide additional information, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a relatively simple fix.  Because I was using django forms, I was pretty easily able to change from displaying the form Textarea:

```
{{ form.paragraph_data }}
```

to displaying just the plain text:

```
{{ form.paragraph_data.initial }}
```

However, this initially caused the newlines to not display correctly, because HTML doesn't process them in a plain string.  So I added some processing in the creation of the form to replace the newlines with `<br />`s:

```
form.fields['paragraph_data'].initial = form.fields['paragraph_data'].initial.replace('\n', '<br />')
```

Finally, I had to add the `safe` filter to Django templating line to tell it to actually render the HTML rather than cleansing it:

```
{{ form.paragraph_data.initial|safe }}
```

Again, this was partially easy because of Django forms, but it should translate relatively easily to a more standard javascript/html solution.