# pdfkit image not embedded using Django

Tags: python, django, pdfkit

I'm converting a protected webpage into pdf using Django and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884654/generate-pdf-of-protected-django-webpage-with-attachments/45947368).

The solution works great except the part that the webpage contains images which do not show up in the pdf and i get an error

```
Warning: Failed to load file:///media/images/main/logo.jpg (ignore)
```

I'm currently using from_string method as follows

```
pdfkit.from_string(msg_html, 'testing123.pdf') #msg_html contains html string with images
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out that url of images in html document that needs to be converted to pdf using pdfkit needs to have an absolute url

in my html file, i had to update my urls as follows:

```
<img src="/media/images/main/logo.jpg">
```

to

```
<img src="https://test.mywebsite.com/media/images/main/logo.jpg">
```

using this i was able to generated pdf containing my logo from the html file